# How to chunk up an a step function array based on when x-values flatten out

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, piecewise

I am running into a problem that I am having trouble figuring out in python (which I will currently blame on sever jetlag).

I have an array, let's call it x. The plot of x where y-axis is generic value, x-axis is index of array, looks like:

[image: y-axis is generic value, x-axis is index of array]

What I want to do is isolate the flat sections after the initial bump (see next picture that I am interested in):

[image: chunks I am interested in]

I want to ignore the leading flat line and bump, and make an array of the five red boxes in the second image such that I have something like

x_chunk = [[box 0], [box 1], [box 2], [box 3], [box 4]]

I want to ignore all of the sloped transition line between the red chunks. I am having trouble figuring out the proper iterating procedure and setting the condition such that I get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is probably not the cleanest solution, however it works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create data
r=np.random.random(50)
y1 = np.array([50,40,30,20,10])
y=np.repeat(y1,10)
y[9]=y[9]+10
y=y+r

# Plot data
x=np.arange(len(y))
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Will give you something like this:

[image: Example data]

```
# Find maximum and start from there
idxStart=np.argmax(y)
y2=y[idxStart:]

# Grab jump indices
idxs=np.where(np.diff(y2)<-1)[0]+1

# Put into boxes
boxs=[]
for i in range(len(idxs)-1):
    boxs.append(y2[idxs[i]:idxs[i+1]])

print boxs
```

Of course you will need to find the right threshold to distinguish the "jumps/drops" in the data, in my case `-1` was good enough since `random` returns values between 0 and 1. Hope your jetlag gets better soon.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested as I have no data, but something like this should work

```
def findSteps(arr, thr=.02, window=10, disc=np.std):
    d = disc(np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, strides = arr.strides*2, shape = (arr.size-window+1, window)), axis = 1)
    m = np.minimum(np.abs(d[:-window]), np.abs(d[window:])) < thr
    i = np.nonzero(np.diff(m))
    return np.split(arr[window:-window], i)[::2]
```

May have to play around with the window and threshold value, and you may want to write a slope function for `disc` if `np.std` doesn't work, but the basic idea is looking forward and backward by `window` steps and seeing if the standard deviation (or slope) of the stride is close to 0.

You'll end up with blocks of `True` values, which you find the start and end of by `np.nonzero(np.diff())`

You then `np.split` the array into a list of arrays by the blocks and only take every other member of the list (since the other sub-arrays will be the transitions).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was thinking about playing around with np.std and the parameters for scipy.optimize.curve_fit for fitting a straight line and minimizing the slope. I wasn't aware of the slide_tricks function, and though the documentation for it isn't very great, it seems to be a neat trick to split up an array.

One quick question:
Why do you do 

m = np.minimum(np.abs(d[:-window]), np.abs(d[window:])) < thr

instead of just doing

m = d < thr

Comment: Mostly so that you don't miss the last `window` datapoints at the end of your steps.  The `abs` is in case you replace `np.std` with a slope function.